# Monthly operations time series with apply.monthly in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts

The problem is to use apply.monthly or any other similar function to do monthly operations with a dataset. The data I have looks like the following:

```
> minidata[1:10,]
          date Month Year TMIN
 1  1948-01-01   Jan 1948  1.1
 2  1948-01-02   Jan 1948  7.2
 3  1948-01-03   Jan 1948  5.0
 4  1948-01-04   Jan 1948  9.4
 5  1948-01-05   Jan 1948  4.4

 > tail(minidata)
     date      Month Year TMIN
 54 1948-02-23   Feb 1948  2.8
 55 1948-02-24   Feb 1948 -0.6
 56 1948-02-25   Feb 1948  1.7
 57 1948-02-26   Feb 1948  2.8
 58 1948-02-27   Feb 1948  4.4
 59 1948-02-28   Feb 1948  3.3
```

Task, use my own function to produce the monthly mean:

```
 mymean <- function(date){
   for (j in 1:days_in_month(date)){
     avg = (1/(days_in_month(date))
           *sum(minidata$TMIN[1:days_in_month(date)])}
   return(avg)
 }
```

The result must be the same as the R function in the xts package:

```
 dat.xts <- xts(x= minidata$TMIN,order.by = minidata$date)
 > apply.monthly(dat.xts,mean)
                [,1]
 1948-01-31 2.312903
 1948-02-28 2.082143
```

My function outputs the correct values:

```
 > mymean(minidata$date[1])
      Jan 
 2.312903 
 > mymean(dat.xts[1])
      Jan 
 2.312903
```

I wouldn't mind if $apply.monthly$ generated a new column with the means, but I have to use my own function! (This is an example, in reality my function is a lot harder).

I tried:

```
 > apply.monthly(dat.xts,function(dat.xts) mymean(dat.xts))
 Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type
 In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Thanks!

Update: days_in_month can be found in the lubridate package. It calculates the number of days in a given month

Comment: Note that your `mymean` function doesn't work for any month other than January; the `1:days_in_month(date)` will always get the first `days_in_month(date)` values, not the values in that month.

Comment: `with(minidata, tapply(TMIN, Month, mean))`? or `with(minidata, ave(TMIN, Month, FUN = mean))` to add it back into your data frame

Comment: what is days_in_month?

Comment: days_in_month is from the lubridate package, calculates the number of days in a month

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is the issue, not `apply.monthly`. I don't know where the `days_in_month` function is defined, but it probably doesn't work with xts objects. I assume it expects a date-time class.

And your `mymean` function references an object that isn't passed to it, which is not good practice because it makes R search for `minidata`.

Your function should expect an xts object containing a month of data and operate only on that data, not some object outside the function scope. For example:

```
mymean <- function(Data) {
  days <- days_in_month(index(Data)[1])
  avg <- (1/days) * sum(Data$Close)
  return(avg)
}
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
apply.monthly(x, mymean)
```

Comment: when I try to replace the Data for my own data I get: Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type. Any idea why? When I do your example I get the same error!

Comment: @Oniropolo: it produces an error because I didn't know what `days_in_month` did. `days_in_month` returns a vector the same length as its input, which causes my function to also return a vector the same length as the input vector.  So no aggregation scheme would work because my function didn't aggregate.  See my corrected example.

Answer (score 0):

To perform operations within groups of a data frame, you can use the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package. For instance, to get the average `TMIN` within each group:

```
library(dplyr)
summarize(group_by(minidata, Month), mean = mean(TMIN))
```

This is often written as:

```
minidata %>% group_by(Month) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(TMIN))
```

Comment: Given the issues with their function, I don't think using a different aggregation function is going to help.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I wasn't using their function at all (largely for that reason). I was suggesting a new, and easier, way of getting the mean within each group.

Comment: "Easier" is subjective. If you don't use their function, `apply.monthly(dat.xts$TMIN, mean)` works and is "easy". And is your first example is correct? How does `summarize` know where to find `Month` and `TMIN`?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich the OP provided the first few rows of `minidata`, which is a data frame with columns `Month` and `TMIN`.

Comment: My question was how `summarize(group_by(Month), mean = mean(TMIN))` knows to look in `minidata` for `Month` and `TMIN`.  Did you mean to include `minidata` in the `group_by` call?

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. The question is how to use one's own function to calculate the monthly mean. And I tried your code with the function by Joshua Ulrich and I can't get it to work

Answer (score -2):

Your function works only on data frames, the `xts` object is different and isn't going to work the way you want. That is why it is giving you errors.

Besides that, you *do not* want to do this with a loop. It is going to take much longer than many other ways of doing it.

David's answer (use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarize`) is the best way to handle this. You can use a custom function in the `summarize` if that is what the problem is. Just define your function and use it there.